# How can I show all matching lines by filtering lines title attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

#myInput is the input box, and #ulmain is the ul id, .abch2 is the line heading class, .abc is the emoji lines class. when a user inputs the name of emoji, then I want to show only all matching lines and hide all other lines including h2 lines of that conainer. I am trying to run with these codes but It's not working.

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var li = $("#ulmain li");
    li.hide();

    li.each(function () {
        var text = $(this).attr('title');
        if (text.includes(value)) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });

});
```

```css
#ulmain {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    display: inline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: arial;
}
#ulmain li {
    display: inline;
}
.abch2 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #383838;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.abc {
    margin-left: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-style: outset;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    border-color: #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 51px;
    height: 51px;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 51px;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inarea">
                <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
            </div>
<ul id="ulmain">
                <li> <span>
                        <h2 class="abch2" id="heart">Heart Symbols</h2>
                    </span> </li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Black Heart">♥</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="White Heart">♡</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Black Heart">❤</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Tilted Heavy Black Heart Bullet">❥</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Heart Exclamation Mark Ornament">❣</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Floral Heart">❦</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Rotated Floral Heart Bullet">❧</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">დ</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ღ</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">۵</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ლ</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ও</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ლ</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="red heart lov️e">❤️️</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Broken Heart"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Heart Decoration"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Two Hearts"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Sparkling Heart"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">❣️</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Heart With Arrow"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Heart With Ribbon"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Revolving Hearts"></span></li>
                <li> <span>
                        <h2 class="abch2" id="star">Star Symbols</h2>
                    </span> </li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Black Star">★</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="White Star">☆</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Outlined White Star">⚝</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Stress Outlined White Star">✩</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Eight Pointed Black Star">✴</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Eight Spoked Asterisk">✳</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Comet">☄</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Circled White Star">✪</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Open Centre Black Star">✫</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Black Centre White Star">✬</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Outlined Black Star">✭</span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Light Five Pointed Black Star"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Five Pointed Black Star"></span></li>
                <li><span class="abc" title="Inverted Pentagram">⛧</span></li>
                <li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> something </title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>

#ulmain {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}
#ulmain li {
  display: inline;
}
.abch2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #383838;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.abc {
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: outset;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-color: #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 51px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="output"></div>
<div class="inarea">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
</div>
<ul id="ulmain">
  <li> <span>
          <h2 class="abch2" id="heart">Heart Symbols</h2>
      </span> </li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Black Heart">♥</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="White Heart">♡</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Black Heart">❤</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Tilted Heavy Black Heart Bullet">❥</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Heart Exclamation Mark Ornament">❣</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Floral Heart">❦</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Rotated Floral Heart Bullet">❧</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">დ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ღ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">۵</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ლ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ও</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ლ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="red heart lov️e">❤️️</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Broken Heart"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heart Decoration"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Two Hearts"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Sparkling Heart"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">❣️</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heart With Arrow"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heart With Ribbon"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Revolving Hearts"></span></li>
  <li> <span>
          <h2 class="abch2" id="star">Star Symbols</h2>
      </span> </li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Black Star">★</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="White Star">☆</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Outlined White Star">⚝</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Stress Outlined White Star">✩</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Eight Pointed Black Star">✴</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Eight Spoked Asterisk">✳</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Comet">☄</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Circled White Star">✪</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Open Centre Black Star">✫</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Black Centre White Star">✬</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Outlined Black Star">✭</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Light Five Pointed Black Star"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Five Pointed Black Star"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Inverted Pentagram">⛧</span></li>
  <li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
         
           var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

           /* in case of empty input, reset all icons */
           if( value === '' || value.trim() === ''){
               $( "#ulmain > li" ).filter(()=> {
                   return true
               }).css('display','inline')
               return;
           }
           /* filter items */
           const filteredItems = $( "#ulmain > li" )
               .filter(function() {
                   const span = $(this)[0].firstElementChild;
                   /* if in case no span , just return to avoid from crash */
                   if(!span){
                       return false
                   }
                   const title = span.attributes['title'] ?   span.attributes['title'].value : '';
                  
                   return  !title.toLowerCase().includes(value)
               }).css('display', 'none');
       });
   })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Dear! I hope this will solve your problem. Further, you can modify this script according to your needs.

Comment: This solution will remove the `Heart Symbols` and `Star Symbols` heading, if any key is entered.

Comment: Dear @Nitheesh !  !title.toLowerCase().includes(value) . Author can modify this statement as per his needs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Logic**

- Select all `li`s inside ul `#ulmain` using `$("#ulmain li")`
- Split the list into two. Heart group and Star group.
- I used this logic. Found the li with heading `Star Symbols`. That is the star group heading. All node after this and including are one group, the nodes before this are another group.
- Loop through complete `li` and check the title attribute of each. If the title matches the input, show it else hide it.
- Check the length of the groups created previously which are visible. If the length is 1, that means only title is visible. In that case hide the title aswell.

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
  var lis = $("#ulmain li");
  const heartSymbolLi = Array.from(lis).find(node => $(node).find("span h2").text() === "Heart Symbols");
  const starSymbolLi = Array.from(lis).find(node => $(node).find("span h2").text() === "Star Symbols");
  const heartSymbolLiList = $(starSymbolLi).prevAll('li');
  const starSymbolLiList = $(starSymbolLi).prev().nextAll('li');
  lis.each(function (index, nodeLi) {
    // Find title attribute of each span
    var text = $(nodeLi).children("span").attr("title");
    if (!text || (text.toLowerCase()).includes(value)) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
  if (Array.from(heartSymbolLiList).filter(node => node.style.display !== "none").length === 1) {
    $(heartSymbolLi).hide();
  } else {
    $(heartSymbolLi).show();
  }
  
  if (Array.from(starSymbolLiList).filter(node => node.style.display !== "none").length === 1) {
    $(starSymbolLi).hide();
  } else {
    $(starSymbolLi).show();
  }

});
```

```css
#ulmain {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

#ulmain li {
  display: inline;
}

.abch2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #383838;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.abc {
  margin-left: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-style: outset;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  border-color: #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 51px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inarea">
  <input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
</div>
<ul id="ulmain">
  <li>
    <span>
      <h2 class="abch2" id="heart">Heart Symbols</h2>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Black Heart">♥</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="White Heart">♡</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Black Heart">❤</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Tilted Heavy Black Heart Bullet">❥</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Heart Exclamation Mark Ornament">❣</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Floral Heart">❦</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Rotated Floral Heart Bullet">❧</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">დ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ღ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">۵</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ლ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ও</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">ლ</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="red heart lov️e">❤️️</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Broken Heart"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heart Decoration"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Two Hearts"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Sparkling Heart"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="heart love">❣️</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heart With Arrow"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heart With Ribbon"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Revolving Hearts"></span></li>
  <li>
    <span>
      <h2 class="abch2" id="star">Star Symbols</h2>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Black Star">★</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="White Star">☆</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Outlined White Star">⚝</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Stress Outlined White Star">✩</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Eight Pointed Black Star">✴</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Eight Spoked Asterisk">✳</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Comet">☄</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Circled White Star">✪</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Open Centre Black Star">✫</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Black Centre White Star">✬</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Outlined Black Star">✭</span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Light Five Pointed Black Star"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Heavy Five Pointed Black Star"></span></li>
  <li><span class="abc" title="Inverted Pentagram">⛧</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a working jsfiddle of your query. The solution is 20 lines of javascript
->     https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/ymrf1269/55/

```
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
 
 var searchInputVal=$('#myInput').val().toLowerCase();
 var li=$('#ulmain .abc') ;
 var txtVal;
 
if(li.get(0).hasAttribute('title')){
   for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  txtVal=li[i].title;
  
   txtVal.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchInputVal) > -1 
        ?   li[i].style.display = ""
       :  li[i].style.display = "none";        
}
 }
})
```

Comment: This will never hide the `Heart Symbols` and `Star Symbols` heading, if there is no search result found.